# how to host Asp.net core web application..?

Tags: asp.net-core, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have more confusion with hosting my application. I Build my application in Asp.net core 3.1.2
after the completion of my development, how to choose my hosting plans. there is so many options are there
Eg: shared hosting and   Cloud Hosting Plans

if I choose windows cloud Hosting, is it work for other os users. 
please guide me. 
(this link => I plan to buy host   )
https://www.asphostportal.com/Windows-Cloud-Hosting-Plans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core can be hosted on Windows or Linux hosts.

Shared hosting is fine for smaller applications or use cloud hosting for larger websites.

The hosting site you linked (asphostportal.com) says they support "All versions of ASP.NET Core" so your app can host there.

If you use Windows hosting then other OS users can access your website without problems.

Answer (score 0):

If choose their windows cloud hosting platform, your .net core will work fine since .net core running perfectly on Windows OS. You can go with this provider, they fully support .net core.